# how to convert Row to column dynamically in sql server

Tags: sql, pivot, row, sql-server-2014

Here is my tables structure

> Result

```
id  ResultId  CategoryId   Total  Attempted  Score
----------------------------------------------------
1     8         1           30      25        20
2     8         2           30      30        19
3     8         3           30      27        21
4     7         1           20      15        10
5     7         2           20      20        15
```

> Category

```
Id     CategoryName
-----------------------
1         General
2         Aptitude
3         Technical
```

I want data in the below format
For ResultId = 8

```
Id     General     Aptitude    Technical    Total
--------------------------------------------------
8        20          19           21          60
```

For ResultId = 7

```
Id     General     Aptitude    Total
-------------------------------------
7        10          15          25
```

I need a help to fetch the data in above format.

> NOTE: The final fetched data contains score from Result table but having a column names from category table and according to CategoryId in Result table. Column name will be dynamic

> Tried the below code (just for testing) but didn't work

```
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(CategoryName)
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT CategoryName 
        FROM [dbo].[Category] c) AS PivotExample
 
 
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT  DISTINCT ' +   @PivotColumns + '
    FROM [dbo].[Category] c
    
    PIVOT( SUM(c.Id) 
          FOR CategoryName IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P'
 
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Comment: Where is the code you have written ?

Comment: I tried by using Pivot but didn't work. I have updated the question

Comment: What database do you use ? Oracle ? SQLServer ?...

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: In your code you are showing us a table: DriveCategories. But in your question you are not showing us the columns from that table, only Category and Result ?

Comment: My actual DB structure is different. Have more number of columns than above. I'm just asking help by giving an overview of structure (Sample) on which I need a help.

Answer (score 0):

My query will give you the expected output. You can check the output in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b22b2/11)

```
 --dynamic with case
 DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000) = NULL
 DECLARE @ColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(4000);

 SET @ColumnHeaders = STUFF((
             SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 'Max(CASE WHEN rn =' + quotename(rn, '''') + ' THEN Score  else null end ) as ' + CategoryName  + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
             FROM (
                  SELECT CategoryName, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CategoryName) rn
                  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT CategoryName FROM Category) t0
                 ) t1
             FOR XML PATH('')
                  ,TYPE
              ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
 --print @ColumnHeaders

 SET @sql = N' ;with cte as (
 select * , Row_number() Over(Partition by ResultId  Order by ResultId ) rn from 
 Result) 
 Select  ResultId, ' + @ColumnHeaders + ', SUM(Score) Total from cte Group by 
 ResultId ';

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```